# twitter integration using OAuth sign post

Tags: android

I want to integrate twitter in my application.Can anybody suggest how should i proceed using 
the cosumer key,token,token secret.I got some code but could not understand the use of the 
cosumer key,token,token secret,callbackurl.can anybody help me giving the complete explanation of each functions,variable  used ?

Answer (score 0):

The oauth-signpost java project should run in Android  http://code.google.com/p/oauth-signpost/

There is some demo code here: https://github.com/kaeppler/signpost-examples/blob/master/OAuthTwitterExample/src/TwitterMain.java